# Visual Basic DLL for C# or Python

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a VB DLL from Maxim for One wire EEPROM communication and would like to port the functionality to another language like C# or Python. Before I venture too far in this path, I would like to know if this is possible? 
If yes, then how can i achieve this?

Comment: if it's a VB.NET .dll, then you just reference it from your C# app and all is well in the world.  No additional effort required.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense since Microsoft products. How about if I want to use Python? There are timing and commands inside the DLL for One wire programming and what would be easiest way to port the DLL into Python?